# Mule Rest component @Context HttpServletRequest returns null always

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Here my configuration code and i heard i have to add servlet specific code for that,unfortunately i did not find any documentation for that

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="192.168.7.121" port="9091" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>    
<flow name="restFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component class="com.syn.rest.test" />
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

and here the class code

```
@Path("test")
public class test {

@GET
public String method(@Context HttpServletRequest request)
{
    if(request!=null)
    return "It works"+request.getMethod();
    else
        return "Not worked";
}

}
```

I tried using servlet-connector instead of http connector by hosting the service in tomcat then also i received null

Comment: Why do you need the "@Context HttpServletRequest", can you specify the information you want to get from it?. Maybe you can use the "@Context UriInfo" instead of "@Context HttpServletRequest".

Comment: I am having the same problem.  @ManuelSaucedo, I believe the user gave an example below of what info he would like from the request in his example.  Similarly, I would also like to retrieve the HTTP method of the request.